# System.Move and Array of String

Tags: string, delphi

I am trying to move some array elements (of string) to some other position.

When I use `System.Move()`, FastMM4 reports leaks.

Here is a small snippet to show the problem:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  TArrayOfStr = array of string;
const
  Count1 = 100;
  String1 = 'some string ';  {space at end}
var
  Array1: TArrayOfStr;
  Index1: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Array1, Count1);
  Index1 := 0;
  while Index1 < Count1 do begin
    Array1[Index1] := String1 + IntToStr(Index1);
    Inc(Index1);
  end;
  System.Move(Array1[0], Array1[3], 2 * SizeOf(string)); {move 2 cells from cell 0 to cell 3}
  ShowMessage(Array1[3]);
end;
```

It probably has something to do with `SizeOf(String)` but I don't know what.

Could someone help me make the leaks go away?

Comment: Why are you not simply writing `Array1[3] := Array1[0]`?

Comment: I could do that --of course. But, there are 2 reasons: 1) Move() is faster. 2) This is just an example, real usage can be (is) much more varied. So, yes, I do need to use Move().

Comment: Problem is Move doesn't work. Doesn't account for ref counting.

Comment: Have you ***profiled*** the difference within normal use of your application? Or are you just guessing about how much benefit you'll get? ... In which case your optimisation is _premature_.

Comment: How can I profile a solution that I don't have?

Comment: How can you "optimise" for a performance "problem" you don't know about?

Comment: I am going by years-long experience in the source code of Delphi. In there, even though {$PUREPASCAL} version exists, they use asm alternatives.

Comment: If you haven't benchmarked your performance, then you should not bother with complaining about slowness. Copying strings in the naive way using a loop is really a very fast operation. Hacking this only leads to problems in (multithreaded) code later on..

Comment: Actually, this whole thing arises from TStringList being slow. I have written one --benchmarked it-- to be around ~40% faster. But, and this is my gut feeling, a FastMoveString() sort of thing would make it even better.

Comment: @Adem My point is you're wasting effort being paranoid about ***potential*** performance problems before you've even confirmed that they are a problem. _Do you realise how **fast** modern computers are?_ Use of managed types provides benefits that the record keeping is done automatically and resources are managed correctly. You can try to do the same yourself, but it will probably be slower and buggier. In the vast majority of cases, if you do have a performance problem it won't be solved by fighting Delphi's managed types.

Comment: As for your benchmarks of `TStringList` .... A lot depends on what you're trying to do with them. How often you're using them in your application. If a particular use in your application is slow, you might find that it's simply not the best data type for that particular scenario. ..... All of which comes full circle to proving where your performance problem is ***in your application*** ... i.e. **not** an artificial benchmark.

Comment: @Craig, I don't agree with the paranoid bit. If TList (that uses pointers) benefits from System.Move(); it is only natural to ask.expect a similar one for array of strings --one that handles ref counting at the same time.

Comment: TList doesn't work with managed types. And even TList can be "slow" in situations where arrays, hash tables, dictionaries, trees, ... are better choices for the given problem.

Comment: @Adem, and therein lies the rub. It is the management of the ref counting and the cleanup that cannot be skipped, besides TStringList also uses a `TArray<string>` internally.

Comment: I did an isolated testing testing. I.e., used the data my app uses but in a separate (demo) app.

Comment: The question has been asked and answered. If you want to have your performance question answered. Ask a new question, explaining the use case and illustrating the problem.

Comment: So if you have an isolated example using realistic data, and measurements of current performance.... ask a new question about what you can do to improve performance _in context_.

Comment: Actually, TList (before Borland, or whatever) made mess of it by adding notifications, was fine. A variance of TList (without notifications) that uses Cardinal/NativeUint is great for hash list. I have also tried trees/linkedlists, nothing is as fast as my version of stringlist --if only I also had move() that handled ref counting :)

Comment: @Adem You aren't thinking at all. The ref counts are scattered all over the place. Not contiguous. And if a ref count goes to zero the object must be freed.

Comment: @Adem, I explained how to manipulate the refcounts, what part of this did you not understand?

Comment: @Johan, it is not that I did not understand it; it is the fact that I need to iterate twice that I did not like.

Comment: @Adam, no you don't you can put all of your hacks in one loop, remember the move does not work by magic (hint: it uses a loop).

Comment: @Johan Adem wants somebody cleverer than us to write some magic code that blits the array copy and handles the ref counts without iteration!

Comment: @Johan, one loop (so to speak) in Move(); and another one --for IncreaseRefCount) stuff- after that. The fact that I did not write the code that does the move operation does not mean it is not another 'loop'.

Comment: @Adem, no everything in one loop: `read old item; decrease refcount; if zero free string; read new item; inc refcount; write new item; next i;`

Comment: Which is exactly what the naive for loop does

Comment: Yes yes, that was my very next comment :-). Seriously, that brings us full circle.

Comment: @Johan, the one you described is the loop you're proposing. But, you seem to forget the fact that there exists another loop in Move() (in the form of repeat-until loop). IOW, we have 2 loops. I'd rather bundle them together so that it handles the ref counting at the same the it is moveing each cell.

Comment: @Adem, the move is a distraction. It creates more problems than it solves. All the while it is **not** that much faster than a regular for loop coping bytes. Just do a test: `move(block)` vs `for loop copying integers`. The difference is not that huge. And the move trashes the cache. The cache issues alone make it a bad idea.

Comment: Doing everything in one (naive) loop has much better cache locality. And thus much better performance.

Comment: @Johan, now it is you who have brought us full circle <g>. How do you know (without having the actual code and benchmarked it) that Move() that handles ref counts would create more problems than it solves?

Comment: If you change the definition of `move` from `system.move` to `Mythical move that works using unicorns` then you have of course won the argument. The `move` you are in fact looking for however is the naive loop. Even using hard core assembly skills the naive loop can only be improved by very a low %. I know because I can picture the assembly of your unicorn move and count the cycles in my head.

Answer (score 4):

**Issues**
The problem you are having has to do with the reference counting of the string.

1. Leaks
   **If** there is already a string in the areas you're overwriting these strings will not get freed. These are the leaks you are reporting.
2. Potential access violations
   You copy the string pointers, but you do not increase the reference count of the string. This will lead to access violations if the original strings ever get destroyed due to going out of scope.   This is a very subtle bug and will bite you when you least expect it.

**Best solution**
It's far simpler to just let Delphi do the copying and then all internal bookkeeping will get done properly.

```
  {move 6 from cell 1 to cell 3}
  System.Move(Array1[0], Array1[3], 2 * SizeOf(string)); 
  //This does not increase the reference count for the string;
  //leading to problems at cleanup.

  Array1[3]:= Array1[0];
  Array1[4]:= Array1[1];  //in a loop obviously :-)
  //this increases the reference count of the string.
```

Note that Delphi does not copy the strings, it just copies the pointers and increases the ref counts as needed. It also frees any strings as needed.

**Hack solution**
You should manually clear the area first.
Using

```
for i:= start to finish do Array1[i]:= '';
```

The next part of this <strike>solution</strike> horrible hack is to manually increase the ref counts on the strings you've copied.
See: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Internal_Data_Formats#Long_String_Types

```
procedure IncreaseRefCount(const str: string; HowMuch: integer = 1);
var
  Hack: PInteger;
begin
  Hack:= pointer(str);
  Dec(Hack,2); //get ref count
  Hack^:= AtomicIncrement(Hack^,HowMuch);
end;

  System.Move(Array1[0], Array1[3], 2 * SizeOf(string)); 
  IncreaseRefCount(Array1[3]);
  .... do this for every copied item.
```

Note that this hack is not completely thread safe if you get the strings from somewhere outside your array.

However if you are really really in need of speed it might be a solution to gain a wooping 2% in the performance of the copy.

**Warning**
Don't use this code to decrease ref counts manually, you'll run into thread-safety issues!

**Need for speed**
It is unlikely that simply coping a few strings leads to slowness.
There is no way to get out of the clean up issues if you insist on using managed strings.
On the other hand the overhead of the reference counting is really not that bad, so I suspect the reason for the slowness lies elsewhere; somewhere we can't see because you haven't told us your problem.

I suggest you ask a new question explaining what you're trying to do, why and where the slowness is hurting you.

Comment: Actually failure to increase reference count doesn't lead to leaks. It's failure to decrease (and free if zero) the destination reference counters that lead to the leaks. The first only creates the possibility of access violations.

Comment: TStringList (which is not an array of string, but of a record) uses this in its Delete() function: "PPointer(@FList[FCount])^ := nil;" I have no idea what it means. I am not sure it could help, either.

Comment: It doesn't seem (to me) to offer any significant speed advantage, simply because I would have to iterate all the moved cells after the Move() operation. I need something that does it all in one go.

Comment: @CraigYoung, yes I was getting there.

Comment: @Adem What you are asking for is impossible. So no, you don't need that. Time for you to step back and think.

Comment: @Adem They are right here, and they are telling you. A. you don't have a speed problem to begin with. B. this code cannot be speed by any serious %. C.Hacking it will lead to all sorts of subtle bugs.

Answer (score 3):

The `String` type in Delphi is a managed type. Delphi keeps record of references and dereferences and automatically releases memory allocated to the string when it's no longer being referenced.

The reason for the leak is that you are bypassing Delphi's management of the string type. You are simply overwriting the pointer that references the 4th string in the array. (and for that matter the 5th as well because of `2 * ...`)  So you now have strings in memory that are no longer referenced. But Delphi doesn't realise this and cannot free the memory.

Solution: write `Array1[3] := Array1[0];`

---

Edit:

I've fully answered your question; giving you everything you need to: 1) Understand why you've got the memory leaks. 2) And make the leaks go away.

Yet you're not satisfied... In comments you've explained that you're trying to improve a phantom performance problem you've conjured up via an artificial benchmark.

- It's been explained to you that the only reason `Move` is a little faster than normal string assignment is that: string assignment needs to do additional record keeping to *prevent memory leaks and access violations*.
- If you insist on using `Move`, you'll need to do said record keeping yourself. (Johan has even demonstrated [how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36086820/224704).)
- And then you complain that this will slow down your `Move` "solution".
- Seriously, take your pick: If you want to use `string`, you can have it a little faster with AV's and memory leaks ***OR*** a little slower but behaving correctly. There's no magic wand waving that's going fix it for you.
- You *could* choose to abandon the **string** type (and all the goodness it gives you). I.e. Use **array of char** instead. Of course, you'll have to do all the memory management yourself, and see how far multi-byte string copying helps you.

> I still maintain that if you ask a new question demonstrating a specific performance problem you're trying to solve, you'll get much better feedback.

E.g. In comments you've mentioned that you're trying to improve the performance of `TStringList`.

I *have* previously encountered a performance problem with `TStringList` in older versions of Delphi. It's generally fine even working with hundreds of thousands of items. However, even with only 10,000 strings, `CommaText` was noticeably slow; and at 40,000 it was almost unbearable.

The solution didn't involve trying to bastardise reference counting: because that's not the reason it was slow. It was slow because the algorithm was a little naive and performed a huge number of incremental memory allocations. Writing a custom `CommaText` method solved it.

Comment: That is what I am already doing and it is slow. I would love a solution in asm (32bit and 64bit). I am hoping there exists one.

Comment: @Adem Wait, you asked how can you profile a solution you don't have. But how then do you know that "it is slow"?  ...... If you have a benchmark for some code that is too slow, perhaps you'll be better off asking a new question about how to improve the performance of that code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding a fundamentally different answer in which I present an option how you can do something you really and truly should ***not*** be doing at all.

> **Disclaimer**: What I describe here is terrible advice and should not be done (but it would work). Feel free to learn from it, but ***don't use it***.

As has already been discussed ad nauseam, your problem is that when you use `Move` you bypass reference counting.

- The solution involves making "internal" reference counting unnecessary by working on the principal that no matter how many times a string is internally referenced, you'll hold only a single count to the string.
- And you'll only remove that single count when you're certain you have no more "internal" references to the string.
- Unfortunately, having abandoned internal reference counting, the only time you can be sure of this is when you've completely finished with your internal array.
- At this point you must first manually clear the internal array.
- Then reduce the reference count of all strings you had previously used by 1.
- This implies you need a separate "master reference" to each string.

> **Warning**
> There are 2 immediate problems:
>
> - You need a second list to track the master reference count; wasting memory.
> - You cannot recover memory used by strings that are no longer referenced internally until you've finished with the internal array entirely *because you've abandoned your ability to track internal reference counts*.
>   (Technically this is still a memory leak, albeit controlled. And FastMM won't report it provided you cleanup correctly.)

Without further ado, some sample code:

```
//NOTE: Deliberate use of fixed size array instead of dynamic to
//avoid further complications. See Yet Another Warning after code
//for explanation and resolution.
TStringArray100 = array[0..99] of string;
TBadStrings = class(TObject)
private
  FMasterStrings: TStrings;
  FInternalStrings: TStringArray100;
public
  ...
end;

constructor TBadStrings.Create()
begin
  FMasterStings := TStringList.Create;
end;

destructor TBadStrings.Destroy;
begin
  Clear;
  FMasterStrings.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TBadStrings.Clear;
begin
  for I := 0 to 99 do
    Pointer(FInternalStrings[I]) := 0;

  //Should optimise to equivalent of
  //Move(0, FInternalStrings[0], 100 * SizeOf(String));

  //NOTE: Only now is it safe to clear the master list.
  FMasterStings.Clear;
end;

procedure TBadStrings.SetString(APos: Integer; AString: string);
begin
  FMasterStrings.Add(AString); //Hold single reference count

  //Bypass reference counting to assign the string internally
  //Equivalent to Move
  Pointer(FInternalStrings[APos]) := Pointer(AString);
end;

//Usage
begin
  LBadStrings := TBadStrings.Create;
  try
    for I := 0 to 199 do
    begin
      //NOTE 0 to 99 are set, then all overwritten with 100 to 199
      //However strings 0 to 99 are still in memory...
      LBadStrings.SetString(I mod 100, 'String ' + IntToStr(I));
    end;
  finally
    //...until cleanup.
    LBadStrings.Free;
  end;
end;
```

NOTE: You can add methods to do whatever you like using `Move` on `FInternalStrings`. It won't matter that those references aren't being tracked because the master reference can perform correct cleanup *at the end*. However....

> **WARNING**: Anything you do to `FInternalStrings` ***MUST*** also bypass reference counting otherwise you'll have nasty side-effects. So it should go without saying you need to solidly guard access to the internal array. If client code gets direct access to the array, you can expect accidental 'abuse'.
>
> **Yet Another Warning**: As commented in code this uses a fixed size array to avoid other problems. Said problems are that if you use a dynamic array, then resizing the array can apply reference counting. Increasing the array size shouldn't be a problem (I recall that being a pointer copy). However, when the size is decreased, elements that are discarded will be dereferenced as necessary. This means you'll have to take the precaution of first pointer nilling these elements before shrinking the array.

The above is a way you can bypass string reference counting in a controlled fashion. But let me reiterate what a terrible idea it is.

You should have no trouble concocting an *artificial benchmark* to demonstrate that it's faster. However, I seriously doubt it will provide any benefit in a ***real-world*** environment.
In fact, if it does you probably have a different problem entirely; because why on earth would be shuffling the strings around so much that time spent there overshadows other aspects of your application?

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure  TamListVar<T>.Insert(aIndex: Integer; aItem: T);
begin
    InitCheck;
    if not  IsIndex(aIndex) then  Add(aItem)
    else
    begin
        Setlength(Items,FCount+1);
        System.Move(Items[aIndex], Items[aIndex + 1],  (FCount - aIndex) * SizeOf(Items[aIndex]));
        PPointer(@Items[aIndex])^:=nil;
        Items[aIndex]:= aItem;
        inc(FCount);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the solution I have come up with. It is heavily inspired by System.Move().

As far as I could see, after doing a number of tests, it seems to work OK --no leaks reported by FastMM4.

Obvioulsy, this is not the hand-optimized asm routine I was after; but given my (lack of) talents in asm area, this has to do for now.

I'd be most appreciative if you commented on this --especially to point out any pitfalls, as well as any other (e.g. speed) improvements.

```
{ACount refers to the number of actual array elements (cells of strings), not their byte count.}
procedure MoveString(const ASource; var ATarget; ACount: NativeInt);
type
  PString = ^string;
const
  SzString = SizeOf(string);
var
  Source1: PString;
  Target1: PString;
begin
  Source1 := PString(@ASource);
  Target1 := PString(@ATarget);
  if Source1 = Target1 then Exit;
  while ACount > 0 do begin
    Target1^ := Source1^;
    //Source1^ := ''; {enable if you want to avoid duplicates}
    Inc(Source1);
    Inc(Target1);
    Dec(ACount);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  TArrayOfStr = array of string;
const
  Count1 = 100;
  String1 = 'some string ';  {space at end}
var
  Array1: TArrayOfStr;
  Index1: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Array1, Count1);
  Index1 := 0;
  while Index1 < Count1 do begin
    Array1[Index1] := String1 + IntToStr(Index1);
    Inc(Index1);
  end;
  MoveString(Array1[0], Array1[3], 2); {move 2 cells from cell 0 to cell 3}
  ShowMessage(Array1[3]); {should be 'some string 0'}
  MoveString(Array1[3], Array1[0], 2); {move 2 cells from cell 3 to cell 0}
  ShowMessage(Array1[0]); {should be 'some string 0'}
end;
```

Comment: This is what you so vehemently stated that you wished to avoid, only poorly and inefficiently implemented.

Comment: First, you've changed the semantics of `Move` because your line `Source1^ := '';` clears the source reference; something that does not happen in `System.Move`. Second, you're failing to consider range overlaps (though maybe that's not too serious). But finally, most importantly and most ridiculously: your code is simply a convoluted way of writing `string(ATarget) := string(ASource)`. You're just hiding it behind obfuscated pointer references and redundant temporary variables.

Comment: Your answer boils down to doing what you were advised in the first place. But in such a way that it looks different just so you can claim you weren't wrong. (And ironically making it more wrong in the process.)

Comment: To put some figures on your solution contra a simple assignment loop as suggested by @Craig : 10 million lines moved from one array to another one, your `MoveString()` 550ms, Craigs assignment 340ms. In the simple assignment I also had an assignment to '' of the source string as you have in your method.

Comment: @CraigYoung, You're right that System.Move() does not clear the source but, then, what it is doing is not 'move' (in literal sense) but 'copy'. I suppose it wouldn't matter if you resize the source array so that all the source cells are removed in that operation, but, in every other case, it means you've just created duplicates --which is not always desirable. I wanted to avoid that. Regarding your other comment: How did I make it "more wrong"?

Comment: @TomBrunberg, I have altered the  MoveString() code, can you run the same tests please (or could I have the sources of that test). Indexed access is fast but usually slower than pointers so I am curious.

Comment: I used `System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch` for timing, changed `Count1 := 10000000;`. `StopWatch.Start` right before `MoveString()` and `StopWatch.Stop`right after. The assignment loop: `for i := 0 to Count1-1 do begin Array2[i] := Array1[i]; Array1[i] := ''; end;`. Again timer Start just before and Stop right after. Your revised `MoveString()` but keeping `Source1^ := '';` comes close but is still slightly slower (but only 15ms). Removing `Source1^ := '';` and `Array[i] := '';` reduces the times to 205ms and 215ms, your being again the slightly slower.

Comment: Your code turns out to be what I was using originally. So I benchmarked both. Using array size 1,000,000 and moving 900,000 cells from 0 to 300. I did this for 10,000 iterations for both debug and release builds, as well as for 32bit and 64bit. Here are the results: 32bit debug: 0.36% {Index access is faster}; 32bit release: -2.96% {Index access is slower};  64bit debug: -4.64% {Index access is slower};  64bit release: 1.69% {Index access is faster};

Comment: No Adem, the code I used was yours as you presented it. Anyway, if your program doesn't do anything else than moves strings around in an array, the few percents you can gain might be important. If on the other hand it sometimes reads and writes files, shows something to the user or communicates with the outer word, saving a few hundred milliseconds seems to be out of proportion. Initially I thought you would realize this when moving 10 million strings takes just hundreds of milliseconds.

Comment: The issue never was  how long it takes to move around 10 million items in an array. We (or, rather, I) were trying to pick the better one among the alternatives. Secondly, looking at the bigger picture (i.e. the app) and saying a difference of a few milisecs isn't important is wrong, IMO. Since this will be a part of a library, it needs to be optimized to do its job as best as it can. After all, why else do you think I would raise this in SO --to get someone to write my homework? ;)

Comment: @Adem The reason I said you're making it "more wrong" is because of your change to the semantics of `Move`. I agree that it is linguistically confusing, but it is what it is. And by changing the semantics of an established operation you make your software inconsistent and more error prone. ... It may be a throw-back to the assembler instruction `MOV`. And bear in mind that code can't physically move memory, at best it can copy values from one location to another leaving the original behind. Even that original cannot be cleared; only set to some other value. (NB ***0 <> null***)

Comment: For the record, computers have a long history of "leaving things behind" when one intuitively expects it to be "destroyed". 1) Reallocating memory to a new larger contiguous location: the source is copied, but left untouched in its original location (for performance reasons). It is also no longer considered _in-use_ so will likely be overwritten soon. 2) When files are "deleted", the data of the file is left untouched on disk (again performance) 3) The reason uninitialised local variables have 'unpredictable' values it that you simply get whatever was left on the stack when it was last used.

Comment: Finally: @Adem you have attempted to justify your premature optimisation effort on the basis that your code will be part of a library. While I agree you want library code to be reasonably fast: the fact is you _cannot know_ the usage patterns! Trying to optimise for a specific ***artificial*** benchmark case to the detriment of code quality and other usage patterns is madness. (NB ***correctness > speed by a LOT***) Believe me: if a user of your library has performance problems moving 10 mil. strings in 500ms, speeding up to 100ms isn't going to help. (They have bigger design issues.)

Comment: I mentioned "correctness > speed"; now let's look at your method. (_Note: if I want to move many blocks of strings within large arrays, I probably shouldn't use an array in the first place._) We'll consider it nonetheless: **1)** Source and Target are untyped, which is error prone. **2)** It is far too easy to specify `ACount` that overruns the end of the array. **3)** The following (assuming copy semantics): `MoveString(Array1[0], Array1[10], 5)` is equivalent to `for I := 0 to 4 do Array1[I+10] := Array1[I]` where 1 is no longer a concern and 2 can be checked via a compiler switch.

Comment: Read @Craig's first comment to the question. And then look at your code. What is the difference between what Craig (and others) suggested and what you have presented?